# How do I add a vector where I collapse scores from individuals within pairs?

Tags: r

I have done an experiment in which participants have solved a task in pairs, with another participant. Each participant has then received a score for how well they did the task. Pairs have gone through different amounts of trials.

I have a data frame similar to the one below:

```
participant <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6)
pair <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
trial <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1)
score <- c(2,3,6,3,4,7,3,1,8,5,4,3)
data <- data.frame(participant, pair, trial, score)

participant pair trial score
        1    1     1     2
        1    1     2     3
        2    1     1     6
        2    1     2     3
        3    2     1     4
        3    2     2     7
        3    2     3     3
        4    2     1     1
        4    2     2     8
        4    2     3     5
        5    3     1     4
        6    3     1     3
```

I would like to add a new vector to the data frame, where each participant gets *the numeric difference* between  their own score and the other participant's score within each trial.

Does someone have an idea about how one might do that?

It should end up looking something like this:

```
participant pair trial score difference
    1        1     1     2       4
    1        1     2     3       0
    2        1     1     6       4
    2        1     2     3       0
    3        2     1     4       3
    3        2     2     7       1
    3        2     3     3       2
    4        2     1     1       3
    4        2     2     8       1
    4        2     3     5       2
    5        3     1     4       1
    6        3     1     3       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that involves first reordering `data` such that each sequential pair of rows corresponds to a single pair within a single trial. This allows us to make a single call to `diff()` to extract the differences:

```
data <- data[order(data$trial,data$pair,data$participant),];
data$diff <- rep(diff(data$score)[c(T,F)],each=2L)*c(-1L,1L);
data;
##    participant pair trial score diff
## 1            1    1     1     2   -4
## 3            2    1     1     6    4
## 5            3    2     1     4    3
## 8            4    2     1     1   -3
## 11           5    3     1     4    1
## 12           6    3     1     3   -1
## 2            1    1     2     3    0
## 4            2    1     2     3    0
## 6            3    2     2     7   -1
## 9            4    2     2     8    1
## 7            3    2     3     3   -2
## 10           4    2     3     5    2
```

---

I assumed you wanted the sign to capture the direction of the difference. So, for instance, if a participant has a score 4 points *below* the other participant in the same trial-pair, then I assumed you would want -4. If you want all-positive values, you can remove the multiplication by `c(-1L,1L)` and add a call to `abs()`:

```
data$diff <- rep(abs(diff(data$score)[c(T,F)]),each=2L);
data;
##    participant pair trial score diff
## 1            1    1     1     2    4
## 3            2    1     1     6    4
## 5            3    2     1     4    3
## 8            4    2     1     1    3
## 11           5    3     1     4    1
## 12           6    3     1     3    1
## 2            1    1     2     3    0
## 4            2    1     2     3    0
## 6            3    2     2     7    1
## 9            4    2     2     8    1
## 7            3    2     3     3    2
## 10           4    2     3     5    2
```

---

Here's a solution built around `ave()` that doesn't require reordering the whole data.frame first:

```
data$diff <- ave(data$score,data$trial,data$pair,FUN=function(x) abs(diff(x)));
data;
##    participant pair trial score diff
## 1            1    1     1     2    4
## 2            1    1     2     3    0
## 3            2    1     1     6    4
## 4            2    1     2     3    0
## 5            3    2     1     4    3
## 6            3    2     2     7    1
## 7            3    2     3     3    2
## 8            4    2     1     1    3
## 9            4    2     2     8    1
## 10           4    2     3     5    2
## 11           5    3     1     4    1
## 12           6    3     1     3    1
```

---

Here's how you can get the score of the other participant in the same trial-pair:

```
data$other <- ave(data$score,data$trial,data$pair,FUN=rev);
data;
##    participant pair trial score other
## 1            1    1     1     2     6
## 2            1    1     2     3     3
## 3            2    1     1     6     2
## 4            2    1     2     3     3
## 5            3    2     1     4     1
## 6            3    2     2     7     8
## 7            3    2     3     3     5
## 8            4    2     1     1     4
## 9            4    2     2     8     7
## 10           4    2     3     5     3
## 11           5    3     1     4     3
## 12           6    3     1     3     4
```

Or, assuming the data.frame has been reordered as per the initial solution:

```
data$other <- c(rbind(data$score[c(F,T)],data$score[c(T,F)]));
data;
##    participant pair trial score other
## 1            1    1     1     2     6
## 3            2    1     1     6     2
## 5            3    2     1     4     1
## 8            4    2     1     1     4
## 11           5    3     1     4     3
## 12           6    3     1     3     4
## 2            1    1     2     3     3
## 4            2    1     2     3     3
## 6            3    2     2     7     8
## 9            4    2     2     8     7
## 7            3    2     3     3     5
## 10           4    2     3     5     3
```

Alternative, using `matrix()` instead of `rbind()`:

```
data$other <- c(matrix(data$score,2L)[2:1,]);
data;
##    participant pair trial score other
## 1            1    1     1     2     6
## 3            2    1     1     6     2
## 5            3    2     1     4     1
## 8            4    2     1     1     4
## 11           5    3     1     4     3
## 12           6    3     1     3     4
## 2            1    1     2     3     3
## 4            2    1     2     3     3
## 6            3    2     2     7     8
## 9            4    2     2     8     7
## 7            3    2     3     3     5
## 10           4    2     3     5     3
```

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you.

Say that I now wanted to have the actual score of the other player in each trial. Could that be done?

Comment: @MarcAndersen You're very welcome! See edit for answer to follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,difference := abs(diff(score)), by = .(pair, trial)]
data
#    participant pair trial score difference
# 1:           1    1     1     2          4
# 2:           1    1     2     3          0
# 3:           2    1     1     6          4
# 4:           2    1     2     3          0
# 5:           3    2     1     4          3
# 6:           3    2     2     7          1
# 7:           3    2     3     3          2
# 8:           4    2     1     1          3
# 9:           4    2     2     8          1
#10:           4    2     3     5          2
#11:           5    3     1     4          1
#12:           6    3     1     3          1
```

A slightly faster option would be:

```
setDT(data)[, difference := abs((score - shift(score))[2]) , by = .(pair, trial)]
```

If we need the value of the other pair:

```
data[, other:= rev(score) , by = .(pair, trial)]
data
#    participant pair trial score difference other
# 1:           1    1     1     2          4     6
# 2:           1    1     2     3          0     3
# 3:           2    1     1     6          4     2
# 4:           2    1     2     3          0     3
# 5:           3    2     1     4          3     1
# 6:           3    2     2     7          1     8
# 7:           3    2     3     3          2     5
# 8:           4    2     1     1          3     4
# 9:           4    2     2     8          1     7
#10:           4    2     3     5          2     3
#11:           5    3     1     4          1     3
#12:           6    3     1     3          1     4
```

---

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(pair, trial) %>% 
    mutate(difference = abs(diff(score)))
#   participant  pair trial score difference
#         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1            1     1     1     2          4
#2            1     1     2     3          0
#3            2     1     1     6          4
#4            2     1     2     3          0
#5            3     2     1     4          3
#6            3     2     2     7          1
#7            3     2     3     3          2
#8            4     2     1     1          3
#9            4     2     2     8          1
#10           4     2     3     5          2
#11           5     3     1     4          1
#12           6     3     1     3          1
```